# Size of a set of sequences

Tags: math

I need help figuring out the size of the set of generated sequences of the following sequence pattern. Bear with me:

A *serial* model A->B->C yields one possible sequence, such as ABC. Therefore, we could consider that a serial model has a set size S=1 regardless of the nodes (i.e A, B, C) and edges (i.e. ->).

A *branch* task model A->B and A->C yields 2 possible sequences such as ABC, ACB. In such a pattern, the size of the set of sequences is given by the number of edges.

However, a task model A->B->C and A->D->E yields 6 possible sequences such as ABCDE, ABDCE, ABDEC, ADEBC, ADBEC, ADBCE. We cannot say that the size of the generated set is given in terms of nodes or edges. Basically, the trick is that in order to execute C I need to execute previously B. Equally, I cannot execute E if D has not been executed earlier. Unfortunately, I do not know how to model this in terms of nodes and edges.

How could I express in a program the size of the set generated in the former pattern with regards to the branches edges and the number of nodes?

Let me give you another example of the last pattern. In case you had A->B->C->D and A->E->F->G the set is all sequences that combine B, C, D with E, F, G, but where D requires C which requires B. Unfortunately I cannot say 6! = 720..I have to applied the restrictions and I don't know how to bring them to paper.

Comment: Can you explain what you've tried so far and where exactly you are stuck? It seems like you're just trying to get SO to do your homework for you.

Comment: Are you looking for a formula for this specific kind of models (i.e. one branch, then serial tasks) or do you need a general formula? In the latter case you probably need to calculate all possible paths.

Comment: Definitely not homework. I am sorry, If I gave you the wrong impression. This has to do with task models applied to user interfaces model based (UIMB). Basically, I generalize the problem for the sake of clarity. I do not need a general formula. 

I would like some pointers about how to represent the restriction. The thing is that the last pattern cannot be represented by saying the combination of all nodes without considering A, namely, size(set(B,C, D, E)= 8. The problem is the restriction that C requires C and E requires D.

Comment: In case you had A->B->C->D and A->E->F->G the set is all sequences that combine B, C, D with E, F, G, but where D requires C which requires B. Unfortunately I cannot say 6! = 720..I have to applied the restrictions and I don't know how to bring them to paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case for a single binary branch followed by two serials of length `k1` and `k2`, the number of possible sequences can be calculated as a permutation with repetition.

You need to choose `k1` times from subset 1 and `k2` times from subset 2. The number of possible sequences is `(k1 + k2)!/(k1! * k2!)`, which yields 20 for your case.

A slightly smaller example `A -> B -> C` and `A -> D -> E` yields 6 permutations, which are:

```
B C D E
B D C E
B D E C
D B E C
D B C E
D E B C
```

Comment: you are the man! What if its not a binary branch. What if A->B->C, A->D->E, A->F->G? will then (k1+k2+k3)!/(k1! * k2! * k3!) apply?

Comment: Thank you nico. So the generalization of the answer then for future researchers with permutations trouble is:

![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/m6lJU.gif